# sql:select rows where two columns value

Tags: sql

how to select rows not in where company=c and leg=2
without specific DB function

```
+---------+-----+
| company | leg |
+---------+-----+
| c       |   1 |
| b       |   2 |
| c       |   2 |
| d       |   1 |
+---------+-----+
```

and get:

```
+---------+-----+
| company | leg |
+---------+-----+
| a       |   1 |
| b       |   2 |
| d       |   1 |
+---------+-----+
```

this is the typical wrong way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  company <> 'c' AND leg <> 2
```

Comment: Where does  company `a` come from in the result? It's not in your sample data?

Comment: Simply `where not (company = 'c' and leg= 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply place these two conditions in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  company <> 'c' OR leg <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
select company, leg
from table-name
where company != 'c'
and leg != 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
 select company,leg from mytable where company !='c' OR leg !=2;
```

result:

```
    +---------+-----+
    | company | leg |
    +---------+-----+
    | c       |   1 |
    | b       |   2 |
    | d       |   1 |
    +---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `not in` for company

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable where company not in ('c')
```